# How to use data attributes with Material UI?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, material-components

I recently started using Material Design React, but I have just come across that data-someField does propagate the value to the dataset map.

Example:

```
<Input data-role=‘someValue’  onChange={this.onChange} />

onChange = e => {
   const role = e.target.dataset.role
   const role2 = e.currentTarget.dataset.role
}
```

Both roles in the `onChange` handler are undefined. This doesn’t happen if I change the `Input` tag to a regular HTML input.

Any ideas why Material Design doesn’t allow data attributes or if there is any workarounds?

Using the suggestion from @Springer, I tried using `inputProps`, but noticed that only the `name` attribute is available, the rest are undefined.

```
<Input
    value={role.name}
    disabled={!this.state.editMode}
    inputProps={{
        name: 'MyName',
        role: 'MyRole',

        dataset: {
            degree: 'Teniente'
        },

        data: {
            roleId: role.uuid
        },

        dataRoleId: {
            roleId: role.uuid
        }
    }}

    disableUnderline={true}
    data-role-id={role.uuid}
    role={role}
    onChange={this.onChangeExistingRole}
/>
```

Comment: use inputProps  to pass what ever you want to your input

Comment: see https://material-ui.com/api/input/

Comment: The reason why none of the fields, but name were working was because they are custom attributes, so you have to put quotes around them:  ```inputProps={{'data-role':'MyRole'}}```. Then you will be able to access them in the handler as follows: ```e.target.dataset.role```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In the react material api they use the `inputProps` to pass extra object (props , data..)

see [doc](https://material-ui.com/api/input/)

> inputProps : Attributes applied to the input element.

by example to add role data attribute you should add to your `inputProps` props the data-role options ( `'data-role':'roleAttrib'` ), the input should look like:

```
<Input   value={role.name}
         disabled={!this.state.editMode}
         inputProps={{
            name: 'MyName',
            'data-role':'role' // <------- add data attribute like this
            ... 
         }} />
```

same thing for other component
Except `<Button>` you add the data attribute directly in component  like

```
<Button  data-your-attrib="value" />
```

Comment: Hi @Springer, thank you for your answer. Would you be kind enough to give me an example on how you would access the values? I tried inputProps, but only the name attribute is available. I will edit the question to show, what I tried. Thank you

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction

Comment: We need an example.

Comment: @JamieHutber , the answer is already accepted , and seems clear ! , by the way I've added an example for other people for more understanding

Comment: How do you do this with <Button> ? :/

Comment: How do you access the inputProps from an event fired from that Input?

Comment: @julio you just add the data attribute directly as mentioned in answer 
`<Button data-attrib="value" />`