# How to add a data attribute to Material-UI Button?

Tags: html, reactjs, material-ui

I want to add a custom data attribute to the Material-UI Button Component like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54961164/9843082). In my case this would look like this:

```
<Button
  inputProps={{ 'data-testid'='clickButton' }}
>
Click
</Button
```

This solution doesn't work because there is no **inputProps** for the Button Component. So how can I set a custom data attribute to the Material-UI Button Component?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You just add the prop directly to `Button`:

```
<Button data-testid="clickButton">Click</Button>
```

[image: Edit Button data attribute]